# IIS Config error on ticketCompatibilityMode

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, config

I host a website on IIS 7. When I double click on the 'Authentication' icon, I get the following error:

[image: capture]

This is the text from the error:

```
There was an error while performing this operation.
Details:

Filename: \\xxxxx\xxx\web.config
Line number: xx
Error: Unrecognized attribute 'ticketCompatibilityMode'
```

When I track the line, I see

```
<forms cookieless="UseCookies" name=".ASPXAUTH" timeout="2160" domain=".hess.com"
    loginUrl="~/Authenticate/Logon" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" 
    slidingExpiration="true" ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40" 
    requireSSL="false" />
```

Any ideas? I had already installed ASP.NET and all the authentication components for IIS. Do I still need to install something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that the attribute is well positionned in your webconfig file:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms"> 
    <forms ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40">
    </forms>
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Also, what is the server on which you are trying to set this ? Make sure it is in the list of the supported platforms for this feature:

```
Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 7, Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core Role not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core Role supported with SP1 or later; Itanium not supported)
```

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.configuration.ticketcompatibilitymode.aspx) page for more information.

Finally, if you do not need this feature, you can simply remove it from your web.config file. Even though this is not a proper fix to your issue, it will make it go away.

Comment: I have this section. I am using Windows Server 2008 and I have installed most of the features of IIS. However, it seems that IIS doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Is the application pool of your website running under .NET4 ?

Comment: Yes. It's running under .NET 4

Comment: Does this problem also happens on another server ? Or with a different website on the same server ?

Comment: You misspelled ticketCompatibilityMode

Comment: Thanks, turns out it is misspelled on this MSDN (where I copied it from)

Answer (score 2):

I saw this error because ASP .NET was not installed correctly in IIS. I don't know how this happened but it was fixed by running this:

```
 %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

For more details on the IIS registration tool see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

fck this project. not working on it anymore. looks like IIS on that VM is missing some components

Comment: well, that is one valid solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer while Googling. Then found [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2659968):

> The TicketCompatibilityMode configuration switch is no longer
>   supported
>
> Because security update 2638420 changes the format of forms
>   authentication tickets, the 
>   configuration switch is no longer supported if security update 2638420
>   is installed and enabled.